# How to invoke anonymous functions which don't have a var?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm trying to invoke the below anonymous function somebody else came up with, but there doesn't appear to be any way to do it as I can't find a variable name for it.

The callstack in the chrome debugger has SomeFunction, followed by (anonymous function), followed by (anonymous function), followed by dispatch, followed by r.handle

**UPDATED QUESTION**

```
(function() {
ss.initClass(Eb, h, {
    SomeFunction: function(a) {
        var b = this.proxy,
            c = new MyStuff;
        c.Id = 5;
        b.SendStuff(c, key.word(this, function(b) {
            0 === b.Code && this.CurrentStuff(a)
        }))
    },
}, m);
})();
```

How do I invoke SomeFunction from outside of that (function(){})? What about from inside it?

I tried using SomeFunction() to invoke it, but it came back undefined.

Would I invoke this by doing

```
function.ss.initClass(eb, h, SomeFunction(), m)
```

or

```
ss.initClass(eb, h, SomeFunction(), m)
```

or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: It appears to be assigned as a property of an object, so `SomeFunction` does not point to it.

Comment: If you have an object containing that you'd need `theObj.SomeFunction(theParam)`

Comment: SomeFunction doesn't appear to have an object containing it, it is inside another function

ss.initClass(Eb, h, SomeFunction: function(a) {...code}, m)

ss.initClass is itself, just inside the parent (function() { ...code.... ss.initClass(Eb, h, SomeFunction: function(a) {...code}, m)}

Comment: You can't access a variable from the outside of the closure in which it's declared. That's the point of closures. Declare it outside.

Comment: How do I access it from inside the closure then?

Comment: What is `ss.initClass`?

Comment: Why don't you just *give* it a name (variable) if you want to invoke it from somewhere else than inside `initClass`?

Comment: Good idea.. thanks!